# how to detect if a button is being pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, button

You see, I don't want to detect if the button was clicked, but to make a command whenever the button is pressed (which, in my case, would be to make the player move)

Comment: What button is the "_button_"? A mouse button? A keyboard button? A button element? Something else? Also please define the difference between "clicked" and "pressed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something (move your player) ***while*** a button is being pressed (down) using the mouse, you can use the `mousedown` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event). It is fired the moment the (mouse) button is initially pressed. This is the moment when you can start moving your player. Then you will want to stop moving your player when the `mouseup` event is fired (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event).